# Fast data recording/logging on a separate thread in C#

Tags: c#, logging, file-io, thread-safety, queue

We're developing an application which reads data from a number of external hardware devices continuously. The data rate is between 0.5MB - 10MB / sec, depending on the external hardware configuration.

The reading of the external devices is currently being done on a BackgroundWorker. Trying to write the acquired data to disk with this same BackgroundWorker does not appear to be a good solution, so what we want to do is, to queue this data to be written to a file, and have another thread dequeue the data and write to a file. Note that there will be a single producer and single consumer for the data.

We're thinking of using a synchronized queue for this purpose. But we thought this wheel must have been invented so many times already, so we should ask the SO community for some input.

Any suggestions or comments on things that we should watch out for would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty confident that your queue will be pretty much ok.  But make sure that you use efficient method of storing/retrieving data not to overhaul you logging procedure with memory allocation/deallocation.  I would go for some pre-allocated memory buffer, and use it as a circular queue.

Comment: Daniel, do you think we can use the .NET queues for this purpose? We're thinking of using the ConcurrentQueue to store pointers to the data, but pre-allocate the memory for the data prior to starting logging.

Comment: What kind of data do you log?  Structs, simple bytes, in fact, my question is about that if data can be serialized easily in packet and read sequentially.  You are low-level here, stay low level.

Answer (score 3):

I would do what a combination of what mr 888 does.

Basicly in you have 2 background workers, 
one that reads from the hardware device.
one that writes the data to disk.

**Hardware background worker:**
Adds chucks on data from the hardware in the [Queue<>](http://dotnetperls.com/queue) . In whatever format you have it in.

**Write background worker**
Parses the data if needed and dumps to disk.

One thing to consider here is is getting the data from the hardware to disk as fast as posible importent?
If Yes, then i would have the write brackground test basicly in a loop with a 100ms or 10ms  sleep in the while loop with checking if the que has data.
If No, Then i would have it either sleep a simular amount ( Making the assumtion that the speed you get from your hardware changes periodicly) and make only write to disk when it has around 50-60mb of data. I would consider doing it this way because modern hard drives can write about 60mb pr second ( This is a desktop hard drive, your enterprice once could be much quicker) and constantly writing data to it in small chucks is a waste of IO bandwith.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Yes I think we should buffer the data and write it in big chunks.

Answer (score 2):

u might need queing

eg. code

```
protected Queue<Byte[]> myQ;
or
protected Queue<Stream> myQ;

//when u got the content try
myQ.Enque(...);
```

and use another thread to pop the queue

```
// another thread
protected void Loging(){
 while(true){
  while(myQ.Count > 0){
   var content = myQ.Dequeue();
   // save content
  }
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
 }
}
```

Comment: Well in this case we'd have to implement locking mechanisms ourselves. The above code does not appear to be thread-safe.

Comment: when u using Queue, u dont have to worry about thread safe at all. when u want to get element in queue, u just dequeue. and there will be no cross thread processing same object

Comment: @Bonshington that is not true. The `Queue` object itself is shared and it's internal state is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation, In my case I used an asynchrounous lockfree queue with a LIFO synchronous object 
Basically the threads that write to the queue set the sync object in the LIFO while the other threads 'workers' reset the sync object in the LIFO
We have fixed number of sync objects that are equal to the threads. the reason for using a LIFO is that to keep minimum number of threads running and better use of cache system.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I guess that MSMQ won't help here, since we have so much data, and MSMQ is somehow high-level API that consumes CPU even when it does very little.